# getContext is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm working on making a basic web application using canvas that dynamically changes the canvas size when the window resizes. I've gotten it to work statically without any flaws but when I create an object to make it dynamically it throws an error

in chrome the error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getContext'

and in firefox it is:

> this.element.getContext is not a function

I've searched the web and it seems like a common problem but none of the fixes mentioned make any difference.

The code is in question is as follows:

```
layer['background'] = new canvasLayer("body","background");
function canvasLayer(location,id){
    $(location).append("<canvas id='"+id+"'>unsupported browser</canvas>");
    this.element=$(id);
    this.context = this.element.getContext("2d"); //this is the line that throws the error
    this.width=$(window).width(); //change the canvas size
    this.height=$(window).height();
    $(id).width($(window).width()); //change the canvas tag size to maintain proper scale
    $(id).height($(window).height());
}
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Your value:

```
this.element = $(id);
```

is a jQuery object, not a pure Canvas element.

To turn it back so you can call `getContext()`, call `this.element.get(0)`, or better yet store the real element and not the jQuery object:

```
function canvasLayer(location, id) {

    this.width = $(window).width();
    this.height = $(window).height();
    this.element = document.createElement('canvas');

    $(this.element)
       .attr('id', id)
       .text('unsupported browser')
       .attr('width', this.width)       // for pixels
       .attr('height', this.height)
       .width(this.width)               // for CSS scaling
       .height(this.height)
       .appendTo(location);

    this.context = this.element.getContext("2d");
}
```

See running code at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/zbaMh/, ideally using the Chrome Javascript Console so you can see the resulting object in the debug output.

Comment: When I try putting that code in, it gives an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined" coming from the line I call the function :   layer['background'] = new canvasLayer("body","background");

Comment: which suggests that you didn't do `var layer = {};` first.  I edited my jsfiddle to closer match your code.

Comment: thank you for solving my problem! and i have always thought using a jQuery selector is the same like using `document.getElementById();`. i thought wrong...

Comment: @Kaiido fair point, but depends on whether you actually want to really change the number of pixels in the canvas, or just change its visual size.

Comment: @Kaiido either way I've updated the code to use both methods.

Answer (score 90):

I got the same error because I had accidentally used `<div>` instead of `<canvas>` as the element on which I attempt to call `getContext`.

Answer (score 42):

Alternatively you can use:

```
this.element=$(id)[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually we get this error also when we create canvas in javascript as below.

document.createElement('canvas');

Here point to be noted we have to provide argument name correctly as 'canvas' not anything else.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This might seem obvious, but you might think you have everything correct, eg: canvas element with an id, but in my case, I had a div element with the same id as well, which caused my error.

Comment: Thank you! This was my issue.
I had done `<div id="the-canvas"/>` rather than `<canvas id="the-canvas"/>`. Changing it to a canvas element solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recently got this error because the typo, I write 'canavas' instead of 'canvas', hope this could help someone who is searching for this.

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when the element you asked to run `getContext` function for isn't true defined canvas or isn't canvas at all so you must check your element.

Answer (score 0):

The value will be at array 0th position.
So we need to do `variable = $("#id") use variable[0]`

Answer (score 0):

This is a Vanilla problem so to solve this just write.

```js
this.element = document.getElementById('whatever canvas id');
this.context = this.element.getContext("2d");
```

And every time use `this.context.drawImage()` I mean whatever functions you are using.
Use it using `this.context` instead of variable ...because its giving error in mine.
So if you are using pure javascript,html file then do the above.

Example:

```js
this.context.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
```

Or:

```js
this.context.drawImage(playerImage, frameX, frameY, spriteWidth, spriteHeight, 0, 0, spriteWidth, spriteHeight);
```

Like this, I hope this will help you