# Uncaught TypeError: c.getContext is not a function

Tags: javascript, canvas

So, basically I've used code from this https://codepen.io/tmrDevelops/pen/jqqmOw on my website.

This is the javascript it uses, there are two errors.

```js
document.ready(function(){
  var c = document.getElementById('canv');
  var x = c.getContext('2d');
  c.width = 600; c.height = 400; 
  var ms = false;
  var w = 0, h = 0;
  
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/131045/404.png';
  
  var set = function(){
    var run, _h, _w, dx, a;
    w = img.width;
    h = img.height;
    x.translate(50, 50);
    a = 30;
    dx = 0;
    _w = w + 50;
    _h = h + 50;
    return (run = function() {
      var inc, i, j;
      x.clearRect(-a, -a, _w, _h);
      inc = ms === true ? 0.5 : 0.18;
      for (j=0; j <= h; i = 0 <= h ? ++j : --j) {
        dx = ~~(inc * (Math.random() - 0.5) * a);
        x.drawImage(img, 0, i, w, 1, dx, i, w, 1);
      }
      window.requestAnimationFrame(run);
    })();
  };
  img.onload = function(){
    return set();
  };
  c.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    return ms = true;
  }, false);
  c.addEventListener('touchmove',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return ms = true;
  }, false);
  c.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    return ms = false;
  }, false);
  c.addEventListener('touchend',function(){
    return ms = false;
  }, false);
}());
```

```css
canvas {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id='canv'></canvas>
```

My browser says in console

> Uncaught TypeError: c.getContext is not a function at glitch.js:3 and glitch.js:47

Error line 3 is  `var $ = c.getContext('2d');` and error line 47 is `}());`
[screenshot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qtet9.png)

Comment: Consider not using `$` as it will clash with jQuery.

Comment: there's now no longer `$` in code and errors are the same

Comment: The said error doesn't seem to occur on the snippet, perhaps you've misspelled the ID name ..? Out of curiosity, why are you returning from the event handler functions, as the returned value is not used anywhere ..?

Comment: May you update the snippet in the question?

Comment: @Teemu i 'forked' it from https://codepen.io/tmrDevelops/pen/jqqmOw kinda can't really answer that questions.

Comment: see this answer it could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808162/getcontext-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0):

You get the error "c.getContext is not a function" when the object you're attempting to invoke the function on (`c` in your case) either does not have a `getContext` member, or that member is present but not a function.

In your case I'm assuming it's not present at all. This suggests that your call to `document.getElementById('canv')` did not return an object.

Try placing `console.dir(c)` after that line to see what the value is. Alternatively, set a breakpoint in your browser and set through your code to see what it's doing.